Understand DwmGetWindowAttribute and DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS
I got {top=0 bottom=393 left=7 right=393} from calling DwmGetWindowAttribute with DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, and cannot understand why the top=0 while a drop shadow can be seen on the top of the window.
If the RECT does not include the drop shadow area surrounding it, how could the top be 0? I thought it should be relative to the RECT given by GetWindowRect, and it should be equal to the left, which is 7.
If the coordinates are relative to the upper-left corner, why is the left not 0? What are the coordinates relative to?
The most detailed reference I can find is on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute)

DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS
Use with DwmGetWindowAttribute. Retrieves the extended frame bounds rectangle in screen space. The retrieved value is of type RECT.

Some useful words on Get drop shadow dimensions of window say:

Note that Extended Frame Bounds are in physical pixel coordinates, and are not affected by the Scaling features of Windows. You may need to convert back to virtual coordinates, or convert the virtual coordinates to physical coordinates to make them match.

I am wondering if it is true.
Any more detailed documents would be appreciated.

As far as I'm concerned, the window RECT (GetWindowRect) and the window extended frame bounds RECT (DwmGetWindowAttribute with DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS) are different.
According to the GetWindowRect doc:

In Windows Vista and later, the Window Rect now includes the area occupied by the drop shadow.
Calling GetWindowRect will have different behavior depending on whether the window has ever been shown or not. If the window has not been shown before, GetWindowRect will not include the area of the drop shadow.
To get the window bounds excluding the drop shadow, use DwmGetWindowAttribute, specifying DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS.



If the coordinates are relative to the upper-left corner, why is the left not 0? What are the coordinates relative to?

I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/4776
This behavior is by design.
Literally switching to 1px of non-client area on the edges wouldn't work out because grabbing the edges with the mouse would be too hard. So, the amount of non-client space on the edges was left as 8px wide, but 7px of that space is now transparent. The programmatic edge of the window is now in a different position than the visible edge of the window.
That is case on the sides and bottom of the window,but wasn't necessary on the top edge.

The takeaway from this is that the "extended frame bounds" and the visible drop shadow are not related (any more).

It seems the top drop shadow is included in the extended frame, which is inside the GetWindowRect. And the other three side drop shadows are not within extended frame, but still in the GetWindowRect.

@BillHong Currently the extended frame is entirely to make resizing via the mouse easier, and the top edge doesn't need the help. The dropshadow isn't part of the equation.
